# How do I configure the Windows 10 Mail app as the default MAPI client

Tags: email, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. In Windows 7, I used [tvhgooglemapi](http://jankeirse.github.io/tvhgooglemapi/) as my default mail app, so I could for instance send attachments from Word or Windows Explorer using Google Webmail, without the need of an actual mail application.

Now that I installed Windows 10, I wanted to give the default Mail app that comes with it a try, so I added my Google account, and I can use it to send and receive mail. 
However, it does not work from Word 2007 (Office button > Send > E-mail) or Windows Explorer (Send to > Mail recipient), and I get an error message (roughly translated from Dutch): "There is no e-mail application to execute the requested action. Create a shortcut in Default Applications in the Control Panel if you have an e-mail application installed".

The Mail app was already set as the default handler for all protocols it can handle (MAILTO, MS_UNISTORE_EMAIL and OUTLOOKMAIL), so I am not sure what to do next. Is that app actually able to handle MAPI mail? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Nothing so far, some users suggest installing Windows Live Mail 2012 application. I tried forcing the MAPIMAIL extension to open with Mail app .exe but then the Send to Mail option disappeared from the Context Menu. Pretty much I like Windows 10, but clearly they have not fixed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Send to ... Mail Recipient uses the MAPI\Send Mail association, or the Send mail command.

The Microsoft Mail app only contains an association for the MAILTO protocol, so you can't set it as a recipient of the Send mail command.

Comment: WTF Microsoft ...

Comment: This is super annoying...  After years of things working well with XP, going to Windows 10 often feels like stepping back to Windows 3.1 where this kind of goofy broken stuff was common.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as windows 7 and 8, which both also shipped with no mapi support. You always have to install your own mapi client now. I think they want it to die, especially shipping his many major versions without such support. Vista was the last to come with it out of the box.